# Where is the __call__() in tensorflow/contrib/cudnn_rnn/python/layers/cudnn_rnn.py

Tags: python, tensorflow, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

Here is an example using CuDnnLSTM

https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/tutorials/rnn/ptb/ptb_word_lm.py

```
  def _build_rnn_graph_cudnn(self, inputs, config, is_training):
"""Build the inference graph using CUDNN cell."""
inputs = tf.transpose(inputs, [1, 0, 2])
self._cell = tf.contrib.cudnn_rnn.CudnnLSTM(
    num_layers=config.num_layers,
    num_units=config.hidden_size,
    input_size=config.hidden_size,
    dropout=1 - config.keep_prob if is_training else 0)
params_size_t = self._cell.params_size()
self._rnn_params = tf.get_variable(
    "lstm_params",
    initializer=tf.random_uniform(
        [params_size_t], -config.init_scale, config.init_scale),
    validate_shape=False)
c = tf.zeros([config.num_layers, self.batch_size, config.hidden_size],
             tf.float32)
h = tf.zeros([config.num_layers, self.batch_size, config.hidden_size],
             tf.float32)
self._initial_state = (tf.contrib.rnn.LSTMStateTuple(h=h, c=c),)
outputs, h, c = self._cell(inputs, h, c, self._rnn_params, is_training)
outputs = tf.transpose(outputs, [1, 0, 2])
outputs = tf.reshape(outputs, [-1, config.hidden_size])
return outputs, (tf.contrib.rnn.LSTMStateTuple(h=h, c=c),)
```

This line :`self._cell = tf.contrib.cudnn_rnn.CudnnLSTM` creates a LSTM layer.

Then it calls the self._cell object

`outputs, h, c = self._cell(inputs, h, c, self._rnn_params, is_training)`

But i didn't find a `__call__()` function in where CuDnnLSTM is defined:
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.8/tensorflow/contrib/cudnn_rnn/python/layers/cudnn_rnn.py

How can it just call the self._cell object without defining **call**() fucntion?

Comment: `tensorflow.contrib.cudnn_rnn.CudnnLSTM` is a subclass of `tensorflow.contrib.cudnn_rnn._CudnnRNN` which is a subclass of `tensorflow.python.layers.base.Layer` which implements `__call__`.

Comment: @FamousJameous  Thank you for replying! But take a look at the arguments it passes, there should be a function that overrides the call() or there is a function that takes such arguments.

Comment: @FamousJameous I find a class called CudnnLSTM where it defines  __call__()    which takes the same arguments as the examples gives. [tensorflow/blob/r1.8/tensorflow/contrib/cudnn_rnn/python/ops/cudnn_rnn_ops.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.8/tensorflow/contrib/cudnn_rnn/python/ops/cudnn_rnn_ops.py)  It is in a  'ops' subfolder

Comment: The signature for `__call__` in `Layer` is `__call__(self, inputs, *args, **kwargs)` so the call in your posted code is valid. You could modify the code to print the MRO to figure out if it is using some other `__call__` but from what I see, it is using the method defined in `Layer`.